# How to build a iOS Master-Detail application with 2 UITableViewControllers?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, master-detail

I am trying to create a Master-Detail application with a `UITableView` controller as both the master and detail. What I need to do is pass 8 strings of data when a row is selected to the detail `UITableViewController`. What's the best way of accomplishing this? I plan to have the detail `UITableViewController` as static cells, not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in the master view controller to access the detail view controller. Then, in the master view controller's viewDidLoad, you can set up this variable so from this point on, all calls to `self.detailViewController` in the master view controller will be sent to the detail view controller. Sample code:

In MasterViewController.h:

```
@class DetailViewController // do not use include here to avoid reference cycles, just identify DetailViewController as a class

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController

// in the interface, declare property to access detail view controller
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

In MasterViewController.m:

```
#include "DetailViewController.h"

// in the implementation, synthesize
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController

@synthesize DetailViewController;

// when the view loads
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // call super method
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // if you used XCode's built-in Matser/Detail application, this will set detailViewController to the detail view controller
    self.detailViewController = (ITLDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

}
```

This way, when you're in the master view controller code, you can call `self.detailViewController.someProperty` or `[self.detailViewController someMethod]`.

Comment: That doesn't work. I am running two UITableViewControllers, not UIViewControllers

Comment: Just change the `: UIViewController` to `: TableViewController`

Comment: Actually, try changing `@property (weak, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;` to `@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;`